# 2015 MBP doesn't want to wake up in the morning

Tags: macos, sleep-wake

Can you help me figure out why my MBP never wants to wake up in the morning? It's a Mid-2015 15in i7. I've looked around for similar posts but most are for older Macs and the solutions presented either don't apply or haven't worked.

I use the computer for work and have it connected to a cinema display. When I leave work I will sometimes tell it to sleep and sometimes just leave it on so Time Machine can do its work. Every morning when I arrive, I will try to wake it by hitting the space bar a couple times, moving the mouse, adjusting brightness, etc. But after a couple minutes both screens are still black. Sometimes I'll try unplugging the external display to see if the laptop screen will wake but no luck. If I close the lid and try to wake it like a normal laptop, nothing happens. Eventually I end up holding down the power button until it shuts off and reboots.

It's a fairly new computer so it's possible something I've installed has messed it up. I have a variety of things installed for work, like Postgres, Memcache, Redis, some Windows VMs, Backblaze, etc. However most of those aren't daemonized and are shut down at the end of the day. Below is the log from last night, starting after a point of inactivity at 9:58pm to me booting it at 9:03am by holding down the power button.

Let me know if there's any other useful information I can provide. Thanks for the help!

```
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: Bluetooth -- LE is supported - Disable LE meta event
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Down on awdl0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 30955.840644: wl0: wl_update_tcpkeep_seq: Original Seq: 3830926402, Ack: 1423930060, Win size: 4096
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 30955.840712: wl0: wl_update_tcpkeep_seq: Updated seq/ack/win from UserClient Seq 3830927015, Ack 1423930060, Win size 166
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 30955.840789: wl0: leaveModulePoweredForOffloads: Wi-Fi will stay on.
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 30955.907428: AirPort_Brcm43xx::platformWoWEnable: WWEN[enable]
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 30955.908312: AirPort_Brcm43xx::syncPowerState: WWEN[enabled]
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: 030957.618111 PRT3@40130000: AppleUSBHostPort::setPowerStateGated: kPowerStateOn -> kPowerStateSleep
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: 030957.618124 PRT3@40130000: AppleUSB20HubPort::suspend: 
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
1/18/16 9:23:31.000 PM kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltNHIType2::waitForOk2Go2Sx - intel_rp = 1 dlla_reporting_supported = 0
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltNHIType2::waitForOk2Go2Sx - retries = 8
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: Wake reason: ?
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::wakeEventHandlerThread
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: No interval found for . Using 8000000
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: No interval found for . Using 8000000
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: No interval found for . Using 8000000
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: No interval found for . Using 8000000
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM syslogd[44]: ASL Sender Statistics
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: Previous sleep cause: 5
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: in6_unlink_ifa: IPv6 address xxxxx has no prefix
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltNHIType2::prePCIWake - power up complete - took 4 us
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 11 unplug = 0
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 1 unplug = 0
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 2 unplug = 0
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 12 unplug = 0
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: TBT W (2): 0x0040 [x]
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltDPPathManager<0>::createPath - path type 0x1: Initial Credits [int=0 src=0 dst=0] NFC Credits [int=14 src=11 dst=14]
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltDPPathManager<0>::createPath - path type 0x2: Initial Credits [int=2 src=4 dst=1] NFC Credits [int=0 src=0 dst=0]
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltDPPathManager<0>::createPath - path type 0x4: Initial Credits [int=2 src=7 dst=1] NFC Credits [int=0 src=0 dst=0]
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 00:25:bc:8b:0a:54
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: en0: channel changed to 36,+1
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 30958.971703: ARPT: Wake Reason: Wake on TCP Timeout
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: IO80211AWDLPeerManager::setAwdlOperatingMode Setting the AWDL operation mode from SUSPENDED to AUTO
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltGenericHAL::earlyWake - complete - took 518 milliseconds
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration begin ]
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration end, bridges 21, devices 20 ]
1/18/16 9:58:29.563 PM imagent[384]: [Warning] No incoming push handler for selector: handler:isConnectedChanged:    topic: (null)   command: (null)   context: (null)
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: 030959.211160 PRT3@40130000: AppleUSBHostPort::setPowerStateGated: kPowerStateSleep -> kPowerStateOn
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: 030959.211165 PRT3@40130000: AppleUSB20HubPort::resume: 
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: 030959.211379 PRT3@40130000: AppleUSB20HubPort::resume: port needs to be resumed
1/18/16 9:58:29.000 PM kernel[0]: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 000000000820 0x5ac 0x8406 0x820, 3
1/18/16 9:58:30.151 PM hidd[101]: [HID] [MT] MTSimpleHIDManager::deviceDidBootload device bootloaded
1/18/16 9:58:30.157 PM Dock[468]: -[UABestAppSuggestionManager notifyBestAppChanged:type:options:bundleIdentifier:activityType:dynamicIdentifier:when:confidence:deviceName:deviceIdentifier:deviceType:] (null) UASuggestedActionType=0 (null)/(null) opts=(null) when=2016-01-19 05:58:30 +0000 confidence=1 from=(null)/(null) (UABestAppSuggestionManager.m #319)
1/18/16 9:58:30.167 PM imagent[384]: [Warning] No incoming push handler for selector: handler:isConnectedChanged:    topic: (null)   command: (null)   context: (null)
1/18/16 9:58:30.188 PM sharingd[407]: 21:58:30.188 : BTLE scanner Powered On
1/18/16 9:58:30.188 PM sharingd[407]: 21:58:30.188 : BTLE scanner Powered On
1/18/16 9:58:30.188 PM sharingd[407]: 21:58:30.188 : BTLE scanner Powered On
1/18/16 9:58:30.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Up on awdl0
1/18/16 9:58:30.959 PM WindowServer[187]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfile: Display 0x04280b82: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 1942884340 }
1/18/16 9:58:32.471 PM com.apple.CDScheduler[321]: Thermal pressure state: 0 Memory pressure state: 0
1/18/16 9:58:32.472 PM com.apple.CDScheduler[43]: Thermal pressure state: 0 Memory pressure state: 0
1/18/16 9:58:32.716 PM WindowServer[187]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfile: Display 0x04248fbc: Unit 4; ColorProfile { -1504230534 }
1/18/16 9:58:33.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 30962.855049: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Wake - Full Wake/ Dark Wake / Maintenance wake
1/18/16 9:58:33.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 30962.855086: IOPMPowerSource Information: onWake,  SleepType: Normal Sleep,  'ExternalConnected': Yes, 'TimeRemaining': 0, 
1/18/16 9:58:33.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 30962.855121: ARPT: Wake Reason: Wake on TCP Timeout
1/18/16 9:58:33.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 30962.855186: AirPort_Brcm43xx::platformWoWEnable: WWEN[disable]
1/18/16 9:58:33.000 PM kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
1/18/16 9:58:33.000 PM kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::wakeEventHandlerThread
1/18/16 9:58:33.258 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.suggestions.harvest: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 10668 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:33.258 PM com.apple.cts[43]: com.apple.CacheDelete.daily: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 39483 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:33.258 PM com.apple.cts[43]: com.apple.backupd-auto: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 740 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:33.258 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.icloud.fmfd.heartbeat: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 496680 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:33.259 PM com.apple.cts[43]: com.apple.CacheDelete.daily: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 39483 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:33.259 PM com.apple.cts[43]: com.apple.backupd-auto: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 740 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:33.259 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.suggestions.harvest: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 10668 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:33.259 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.icloud.fmfd.heartbeat: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 496680 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:33.000 PM kernel[0]: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
1/18/16 9:58:33.865 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Update: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 1912 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:33.865 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.suggestions.harvest: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 10668 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:33.865 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.icloud.fmfd.heartbeat: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 496680 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:34.000 PM kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::handleWakeEvent_gated
1/18/16 9:58:36.579 PM corecaptured[13271]: Got an XPC error: Connection invalid
1/18/16 9:58:36.579 PM corecaptured[13271]: CCProfileMonitor::freeResources done
1/18/16 9:58:36.580 PM corecaptured[13271]: CCDataTap::profileRemoved, Owner: com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family, Name: AssociationEventHistory
1/18/16 9:58:36.580 PM corecaptured[13271]: CCLogTap::profileRemoved, Owner: com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family, Name: OneStats
1/18/16 9:58:36.581 PM corecaptured[13271]: CCLogTap::profileRemoved, Owner: com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360.0, Name: DriverLogs
1/18/16 9:58:36.581 PM corecaptured[13271]: CCLogTap::profileRemoved, Owner: com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family, Name: IO80211AWDLPeerManager
1/18/16 9:58:36.582 PM corecaptured[13271]: CCDataTap::profileRemoved, Owner: com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360.0, Name: StateSnapshots
1/18/16 9:58:38.000 PM kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::handleWakeEvent_gated
1/18/16 9:58:39.643 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Update: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 1906 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:39.643 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.suggestions.harvest: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 10662 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:39.643 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.icloud.fmfd.heartbeat: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 496674 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:39.644 PM com.apple.CDScheduler[321]: Thermal pressure state: 1 Memory pressure state: 0
1/18/16 9:58:39.645 PM com.apple.cts[43]: com.apple.CacheDelete.daily: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 39477 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:39.646 PM com.apple.cts[43]: com.apple.backupd-auto: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 734 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:39.646 PM com.apple.CDScheduler[43]: Thermal pressure state: 1 Memory pressure state: 0
1/18/16 9:58:39.651 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Update: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 1906 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:39.651 PM com.apple.cts[43]: com.apple.CacheDelete.daily: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 39477 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:39.651 PM com.apple.cts[43]: com.apple.backupd-auto: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 734 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:39.651 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.suggestions.harvest: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 10662 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:39.651 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.icloud.fmfd.heartbeat: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 496674 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:49.879 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Update: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 1896 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:49.880 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.suggestions.harvest: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 10652 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:49.880 PM com.apple.CDScheduler[321]: Thermal pressure state: 0 Memory pressure state: 0
1/18/16 9:58:49.880 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.icloud.fmfd.heartbeat: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 496664 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:49.881 PM com.apple.cts[43]: com.apple.CacheDelete.daily: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 39467 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:49.881 PM com.apple.CDScheduler[43]: Thermal pressure state: 0 Memory pressure state: 0
1/18/16 9:58:49.881 PM com.apple.cts[43]: com.apple.backupd-auto: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 724 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:49.884 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Update: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 1896 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:49.884 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.suggestions.harvest: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 10652 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:49.884 PM com.apple.cts[43]: com.apple.CacheDelete.daily: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 39467 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:49.884 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.icloud.fmfd.heartbeat: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 496664 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:58:49.884 PM com.apple.cts[43]: com.apple.backupd-auto: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 724 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:59:00.124 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Update: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 1885 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:59:00.125 PM com.apple.CDScheduler[321]: Thermal pressure state: 1 Memory pressure state: 0
1/18/16 9:59:00.125 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.suggestions.harvest: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 10641 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:59:00.125 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.icloud.fmfd.heartbeat: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 496653 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:59:00.126 PM com.apple.cts[43]: com.apple.CacheDelete.daily: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 39456 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:59:00.126 PM com.apple.CDScheduler[43]: Thermal pressure state: 1 Memory pressure state: 0
1/18/16 9:59:00.126 PM com.apple.cts[43]: com.apple.backupd-auto: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 713 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:59:00.133 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Update: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 1885 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:59:00.133 PM com.apple.cts[43]: com.apple.CacheDelete.daily: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 39456 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:59:00.133 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.suggestions.harvest: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 10641 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:59:00.133 PM com.apple.cts[43]: com.apple.backupd-auto: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 713 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:59:00.133 PM com.apple.cts[321]: com.apple.icloud.fmfd.heartbeat: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 496653 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:59:08.224 PM com.apple.cts[43]: com.apple.CacheDelete.daily: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 39448 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:59:08.224 PM com.apple.cts[43]: com.apple.backupd-auto: scheduler_evaluate_activity told me to run this job; however, but the start time isn't for 705 seconds.  Ignoring.
1/18/16 9:59:18.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 31008.056706: wl0: setup_keepalive: interval 900, retry_interval 30, retry_count 10
1/18/16 9:59:18.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 31008.056746: wl0: setup_keepalive: Local IP: 10.0.1.193
1/18/16 9:59:18.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 31008.056766: wl0: setup_keepalive: Remote IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
1/18/16 9:59:18.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 31008.056788: wl0: setup_keepalive: Local port: 62578, Remote port: xxxx
1/18/16 9:59:18.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 31008.056811: wl0: setup_keepalive: Seq: 1112791255, Ack: 2289416760, Win size: 4096
1/18/16 9:59:18.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 31008.056932: wl0: MDNS: IPV4 Addr: 10.0.1.193
1/18/16 9:59:18.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 31008.056954: wl0: MDNS: IPV6 Addr: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
1/18/16 9:59:18.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 31008.056974: wl0: MDNS: 2 SRV Recs, 2 TXT Recs
1/18/16 9:59:18.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 31008.056991: wl0: MDNS: 2 TCP ports:  445  548 
1/18/16 9:59:19.000 PM kernel[0]: PM response took 1037 ms (54, powerd)
1/18/16 9:59:19.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 31009.060241: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Sleep 
1/18/16 9:59:19.000 PM kernel[0]: ARPT: 31009.060305: IOPMPowerSource Information: onSleep,  SleepType: Normal Sleep,  'ExternalConnected': Yes, 'TimeRemaining': 0, 
1/18/16 9:59:19.000 PM kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
1/19/16 9:03:49.000 AM bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1453223029 0
```